# Adding a RHV Provider to Cloudform with User not privileged

Tags: redhat

I need to update the user admin of the RHV provider by another User. Is this possible ?, or what attributes does a different user need to have to work well with Cloudform?

References:
In the section 8 of 1.2.1 the information isn't clear: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_cloudforms/4.2/html-single/managing_providers/index

It works well with user admin@internal, but not is mentioned if another user (users of RHV) can connect to the RHV from Cloudform.

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,
Javier